# Extra Text in Home URL

Tags: plugins, themes

When I try to access my main URL when just typing it in the address bar, the URL has this appended to the end: `?route=common%2Fhome`

I've asked my host, WP Engine, and they don't have anything that would have caused this. I'm not sure what plugin would cause this, and I don't know where it's coming from.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend providing some more detail, otherwise you're going to get a bunch of speculating answers or ‍♂️.

Comment: By just googling for `wordpress "?route=common home"` I get: https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=157191 and http://webpactdesigns.com/blogswebpact/remove-index-phproutecommonhome-url-opencart/ and http://vishalramani.in/coding/redirect-home-page-opencart/ and many more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the above responses. I did not have opencart installed, and those were the only similar answers I could find.

I ended up just installing the "Redirection" plugin which seemed to solve my problem. I added a simple redirect which redirected the target URL back to the homepage. I could have eventually found a way to fix it with .htaccess but I was not having much luck and this was a quick and effective solution.